# Copy column with a length greater than the column where I want to place the data - python Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, copy, multiple-columns

I have 2 .csv files, let's say files A and B, one of the columns in file 'A' has 7 things, like this:

```
ID
12 
23
23
12
23
23
23
```

I want to copy this whole column and paste it into file 'B' in column 'ID'. File B contains 2 rows of hard coded data like this:

```
CODE ID SSN NAME
5
5
```

when i do:

```
nameofmydataframeB['ID'] = nameofmydataframeA['ID']
```

the problem I have is that file 'B' ends up only having 2 items, instead of the 7 I want to copy, like this:

```
ID CODE SSN NAME
12             5
23             5
```

I am having a hard time putting this into a question to google, if anyone has seen this before, what did you do?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) for removing column `ID` from `nameofmydataframeB` and subset `[['ID']]` for selecting only column `ID` in `nameofmydataframeA`:

```
print (pd.concat([nameofmydataframeA[['ID']], 
                  nameofmydataframeB.drop('ID', axis=1)], axis=1))
   ID  CODE  SSN  NAME
0  12   5.0  NaN   NaN
1  23   5.0  NaN   NaN
2  23   NaN  NaN   NaN
3  12   NaN  NaN   NaN
4  23   NaN  NaN   NaN
5  23   NaN  NaN   NaN
6  23   NaN  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: I will give that a try, thank you for the quick response @jezrael

Comment: Thank you, that did work, I think I accepted the answer correctly. thanks!